# bootstrap 4 scss theme color override

Tags: bootstrap-4

got my scss file and everything setup correctly but in the below code, the background-color on .header-top is still pulling the color from the original scss files and not the orange color that i have on theme-color variable i wrote.

```
// Variable Overrides (This needs to be before the @import below that 
imports all bootstrap sass files)
$greyLight: #f7f9fc;

// $theme-colors: (
//     "primary": #0077bc,
//     "secondary": #585858
// );

$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #d95700,
  "secondary": #585858
);

$primary: theme-color("primary");

// MY STYLES
.header-top {
    background-color: $primary;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
}


// Bootstrap Sass files ( @import imports everything below)
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: I think i got it fixed but would like to make sure this is the correct way to do it or there wont be any issues later. i moved the @import step to the top of the scss file.

Comment: had an issue with btn-primary not working right so i moved the import step to just above the primary variable and it fixed the button.